# keeping only 5 items in a listbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to create a simple listbox, which is binded to a linkedlist.
The list should only ever hold 5 items at any given time.
When a new item is added, it should check if item count `>= 5` and then remove the last item and add the new item to the top.

To do this, I made this test app:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    LinkedList<string> list01 = new LinkedList<string>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        list01.AddFirst("AAA");
        list01.AddFirst("BBB");
        list01.AddFirst("CCC");

        listBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(list01, "");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (list01.Count >= 5)
            list01.RemoveLast();

        list01.AddFirst(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        listBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(list01, "");
    }
}
```

It appears, when ever I add a new item, I have to keep setting the datasource to a new bindingsource for the added item to show on the U.I.

Is there way to initisalise one binding source, and when the items in it changes, auto update the listbox without having to set the datasource every time you add a new item?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use `BindingList<T>` or `ObservableCollection<T>` ? or you're not aware of them?

Comment: I am aware of `BindingList<T>` and know that it doesn't have the methods I want on it `AddTop` and `RemoveLast`

Comment: How would you remove the last item from a `BindingList<T>` and add an item to the top / first?

Comment: It's not that hard to implement those method yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a collection which implements collection changed notification. There are two options you have `BindingList<T>` and `ObservableCollection<T>`.

Pick any one, From your comment it seems you're just looking for `AddFirst` and `RemoveLast`. You can create a extension method yourself which does that.

```
public static class BindingListExtension
{
    public static void AddFirst<T>(this BindingList<T> list, T item)
    {
        list.Insert(0, item);
    }

    public static void RemoveLast<T>(this BindingList<T> list)
    {
        list.RemoveAt(list.Count - 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on `Sriram Sakthivel's` suggestion, I have achieved my requirement like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    BindingList<string> list01 = new BindingList<string>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.DataSource = list01;

        list01.Add("AAA");
        list01.Add("BBB");
        list01.Add("CCC");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (list01.Count >= 5)
            list01.RemoveAt(4);

        list01.Insert(0, DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }
}
```